# maven plugin share dependencies as provided

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

i want to know, if it is possible to provide dependencies from a custom maven-plugin to the project that include this plugin.

Example:
I have project a-maven-plugin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project ...>
    <groupId>some</groupId>
    <artifactId>a-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>xxx</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And a project that include this plugin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>some</groupId>
    <artifactId>a-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>some</groupId>
                <artifactId>a-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>some.goal</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Now i want that the `a-project` has `com.google.guava:guava:xxx` with scope `provided` as dependencies.
Optimal i can choose in the in the plugin-pom which dependency i want to provide, that i only provide a part not all.

Is there a simple way?

Comment: Plugins have their dependencies and the project it's own...What kind of plugin are you using ? Or what kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: What kind of plugin are you using --> like i write in the fist sentence: a custom plugin, created by me. I try to solve api-dependencies for the plugin. Its generated code from a file used my api with the plugin. But the editors throw warning, because the don't know the dependency. Now my custom plugin should add the depenceny too, so that the editor can resolve it.

Comment: Your plugin can't add dependencies to the project. The dependencies are in the pom file for the project.